# Can't get data from fetch API inside a function

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The application is a web dictionary.

I'm trying to get the data from a fetch API, that uses the value from the input (string), to display the info on the screen. It is inside a object `Main`, that has its `cacheSelectors` (gets all the elements), the `bindEvents`(listeners), the Events and the API.

As I'm not used to this kind of code structure, I'm confused on how it works. If it was outside the `Main` object, it would work just fine, as I would put then function inside the `.then` (function) and in the function I would get the data as a parameter.

```
const Main = {

  init: function () {
    this.cacheSelectors()
    this.bindEvents()
    
  },

  cacheSelectors: function () {
    this.wordInput = document.querySelector('#wordInput')
    this.mainWord = document.querySelector('#mainWord')
    

  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    this.wordInput.addEventListener('input', this.Events.searchWord_input.bind(this))
    
  },

  Events: {
    searchWord_input: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      
    }

  },

  API: function () {
    if (wordInput.value) {
      fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${wordInput.value}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(this.Events.searchWord_input)
        .catch(function () {
          alert('ERROR!!!')
        })
    }
    
  },

}

Main.init()
```

Comment: You never call `API`

Comment: what do i call?

Comment: Everything **except** `API`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can return the `Promise` from `fetch` in `API`, then you can wait for it in the `Events.searchWord_input` function.

```js
const Main = {
    init: function() {
        this.cacheSelectors()
        this.bindEvents()
    },
    cacheSelectors: function() {
        this.wordInput = document.querySelector('#wordInput')
        this.mainWord = document.querySelector('#mainWord')
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        this.wordInput.addEventListener('input', this.Events.searchWord_input.bind(this))
    },
    Events: {
        searchWord_input: function(e) {
            if (this.wordInput.value) {
                this.API().then(data => console.log(data));
            }
        }
    },
    API: function() {
        return fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${wordInput.value}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(function() {
                alert('ERROR!!!')
            });
    },
}
Main.init();
```

```html
Enter word: <input id="wordInput">
```